# why is std::variant permitted to hold the same type more than once?

Tags: c++

What can be the use case of `std::variant` holding the same type more than once?

Refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

You can only find the issue when you start to call `std::get<T>(v)`.

Comment: I guess historical as a replacement for `union` which can also hold multiple values of the same type. Use get by index in this case.

Comment: Excellent for generic code. If you have two types that you don't know, you could do `std::variant<T, U>`, and if `T` and `U` happen to be the same, that's okay

Comment: For my usage I would choose to unique the types before passing it to `std::variant`. The use case is to detect the type of some temp result and store them in the context. And I choose to use `std::array<std::variant<unique types>, sizeof all types>` as the memholder. Here is the codes: https://github.com/BowenFu/matchit.cpp/blob/98b0862fdd970832b6286b5c5f2959681977c1e4/develop/matchit/patterns.h#L261

Comment: This is one of the situations where I would put the burden of proof on the person who wants more restrictions (a.k.a. the opposite of "keep it simple"). Why should `std::variant` be made more complicated by restricting what combinations of types it can hold? What is wrong with allowing greater functionality? Why prevent someone from discovering a use case in the future?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say we want to represent a token that can be a keyword, an identifier, or a symbol.  One possible implementation is thus:

```cpp
enum TokenType : std::size_t {
    Keyword = 0, Identifier = 1, Symbol = 2
};

using Token = std::variant<std::string, std::string, char>;
```

Now it is possible to use, for example:

```cpp
std::get<TokenType::Keyword>(token)
```

to access the alternatives.

Whether this is a good idea is of course up for debate, but it does show the existence of such use cases.

Answer (score 8):

std variant is designed for use in generic code as a sum type.

It needs the algebraic property that a variant merge of two variants a and b (only one of which is active) holds alternative index equal to a if a was active, and count of alternatives in a plus the alternative index of b if b is active.

Because, honestly, anything else is madness there.

Fundamentally, the names of variant members is the index, not the type.

You are free to write a variant alias that bans duplicate types for your own code.  It is relatively easy.

If that (type alternative named variants) was the base, writing index based variants would be quite annoying.

With reflection, making variants with named alternatives will also be plausible.  Again, this would be harder if we blocked index based variants with duplicate types.